# How to create a Content Mapping Sheet of huge amount of data stored on local server?

Tags: sql, excel, mapping

I have huge amount of data in my local server for which I need a mapping sheet which will contain various categories like CAT,SUBCAT,DATE, ID, Path(path of individual content), DIMENSION, etc.

Here's one sample:
[image]

This mapping sheet contains approx 35000 rows.
For each row in above mapping sheet, I have created Insert Queries and stored them in .SQL file.

So, how do I create such mapping sheet of my own data.

Comment: Rather put the sample as text in the question.

Comment: Sorry. I tried but I can't. Too much data and it is not fitting the frame of question.